# The meaning of "yell" in gambling

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, terminology

From movie Kingpin:

> (At a casino table, a customer to the dealer) You are going to give me $100,000 on the line and a $50,000 **yell**, okay?

Does *on the line* mean the money wagered? Then what does *yell* mean here?

Comment: I checked the scene in the movie and I confirm the character seems to be saying "yell".   In the game of craps, *on the line* is (I believe) the straight "pass" line, and I guess *yell* is a specific dice roll, but I have no idea which.  Possibly 11, although most craps websites call that a "yo", not a "yell".

Comment: Just a guess: Can it mean that the player will later *yell/announce* what type of bet the second one will be? I know people tell a craps dealer which wager they want to make, then the dealer will move chips or money onto the right spot on the table. I don't know when the cut-off is for making a bet, though. Is it something like "yell" what I want to bet on before the dice hit the table, or leave the roller's hand, or whatever?

Comment: @JimReynolds: I would be very surprised if that were the case. Casinos generally do not like settling arguments over whether you placed the bet too late, so they would normally cut off betting well before the dice are in the air.

Comment: I did not see the movie, and I do not have it handy now. From the context, could "yell" be "yellow"? I know that usual colors are red and black for several games, but still...

Comment: @Kev "Casinos generally do not like ... ." although this seems common sense, you state it as if it's a fact. So: evidence? "They would normally ...." Ok. Do you know when they cut off betting or don't you? If so, why don't you share your knowledge with us and specify the rule? And your uses of "generally" and "normally" imply that you are aware of exceptions to each statement. Please elaborate those. Would be very interesting to know.

Comment: @JimReynolds: This is ELL , not gambling.SE. Please ask a question on the appropriate site so as to avoid cluttering OP's inbox with irrelevant information.